# Postgres profiling fetching time

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization

I am storing high-frequency price data in Postgres. The table is indexed and the query correctly uses the index, which I can confirm by EXPLAIN ANALYZE result:

```
Index Scan using ix_minute_contract_id_source_id_bar_open_dt on bars_minute tb  (cost=0.58..19899291.37 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=1.418..3169.181 rows=4724529 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((contract_id = 10726) AND (source_id = 6) AND (bar_open_dt >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (bar_open_dt <= '2022-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Filter: (sub_source_id IS NULL)
Planning Time: 0.139 ms
Execution Time: 3249.658 ms
```

Then when reading the data from Python takes about 30 seconds. From the logs I can see:

```
4,724,529 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 41 s 117 ms (execution: 4 s 395 ms, fetching: 36 s 722 ms)
```

So my understanding is that EXPLAIN ANALYZE is quite accurate in calculating execution time but it does not take into account fetching time.

From [Does PostgreSQL Explain Analyze Execution Time consider Fetching time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148686/does-postgresql-explain-analyze-execution-time-consider-fetching-time) I understand that the latter is influenced by memory, CPU and network. Is there a way to profile the fetching part to trace what exactly slows down the query?

**UPDATE 1**

Adding table definition and client example:

```
create table bars_minute
(
    id bigserial constraint pk_bars_minute primary key,
    contract_id   integer   not null constraint fk_bars_minute_contract_id_contracts references contracts,
    source_id     integer   not null constraint fk_bars_minute_source_id_sources references sources,
    bar_open_dt   timestamp not null,
    price_open    double precision,
    price_high    double precision,
    price_low     double precision,
    price_close   double precision,        
    constraint uq_bars_minute_contract_id unique (contract_id, source_id, bar_open_dt)
);

create index ix_minute_contract_id_source_id_bar_open_dt on bars_minute (contract_id, source_id, bar_open_dt);
```

And client:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='user' host='localhost' password='pwd'")
sql = """
    SELECT bar_open_dt, price_open, price_high, price_low, price_close
    FROM bars_minute
    where contract_id = 1
      AND bar_open_dt >= '2010-01-01'
      AND bar_open_dt <= '2022-09-30'
      AND source_id = 1
    ORDER BY bar_open_dt;
"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
rows = cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**UPDATE 2**

As @jjanes suggested that the bottleneck might be in PyCharm, I indeed confirmed that the query in PyCharm console takes 2x time vs Python client. I was originally using SQLAlchemy connection with psycopg2 driver, which would take 17 seconds. I then tried using psycopg2 directly (again, as @jjanes suggested), which resulted in:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)  # 3 seconds
rows = cur.fetchall()  # 5 seconds
df = pd.DataFrame(rows) # 3 seconds
```

totalling in 11 seconds.

Is it right to assume at this point that this is as good as it can be given the EXPLAIN ANALYZE results?

Comment: Are the client and server on the same computer, or is the query traversing a network?

Comment: Yes, the client and the server are on the same computer

Comment: That is not a familiar log message to me.  What log was it, and what did you do to configure it?

Comment: That’s PyCharm/DataGrip console output message (when running queries in PyCharm console)

Comment: This is almost certainly a bottleneck in pycharm/DataGrip, so you would need to do the profiling there.  So you would need to show the client code, and tag the question with those, except it also is not really a DBA topic then.

Comment: I see. Actually only attached PyCharm output for convenience only, reading from Python takes similar time (using psycopg2g)

Comment: In my experience, psycopg2 (is the last 'g' a typo?) is quite fast and probably doesn't explain such a large slowdown when running on the same machine as the db server, unless it is memory constrained and needs to large amounts of swapping/paging, or you are using some db types which are much slower to parse than the ones I normally use.  Could you show reproducible table definition and python code?

Comment: Added the table definition and an example of a client along with some results. In short, @jjanes was right about both the bottlenecks on PyCharm side and psycopg2 being fast. Now just curious if the results can be improved any further